# Why is nextds macros incorrectly expanded in subdags?

Tags: python, airflow

I wrote a DAG with a SubDag inside it:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.subdag import SubDagOperator
from pendulum import datetime


def subdag(parent_dag: DAG):
    with DAG("{}.SubDag".format(parent_dag.dag_id),
             default_args=parent_dag.default_args,
             start_date=parent_dag.start_date,
             schedule_interval=parent_dag.schedule_interval) as dag:
        BashOperator(
            task_id="operator",
            bash_command="sleep 1",
            env=dict(
                DS="{{ds}}",
                NEXTDS="{{next_ds}}"
            ))
    return dag


with DAG("MyParentDag",
         schedule_interval="0 2 * * *",
         start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
         catchup=False) as dag:
    subdag_op = SubDagOperator(task_id="SubDag",
                               subdag=subdag(dag),
                               dag=dag
                               )
```

This DAG (and its sub-DAG) is scheduled daily: `schedule_interval="0 2 * * *"`.

As you can see, the operator inside the subdag rely on the `next_ds` macro.

However, when running the DAG, here is the rendered template for the BashOperator:

```
{
    "DS": "2021-05-19",
    "NEXTDS": "2021-05-19"
}
```

I lanched the DAG today (2021-05-20). So, the `DS` is OK, but I expect the `NEXTDS` to be 2021-05-20.

Why is it expanded incorrectly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue in Airflow 2.0 see [open bug](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/14572) about it.

Since SubDag is a [deprecated feature](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/12292) it's not a priority to fix it.

I encourage you to switch to [TaskGroups](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts.html#taskgroup) which is the replacement for SubDags

Comment: Thanks. It seems that I didn't thoroughly searched though the issues. I will give a try to the TaskGroup or move everything to the same level.